# PHP Websocket to Node/Sockjs

Tags: php, node.js

I have a NodeJS server with SockJS. Clients connect to the node server fine creating a websocket through the browser. The problem is trying to create a websocket from php to node.

I am using the file at https://github.com/lemmingzshadow/php-websocket/blob/master/client/lib/class.websocket_client.php as a means to create the websocket in php.

the server is running on port 9999 and the connection is made in the browser with wss://nodejs.example.com:9999/sockjs/websocket. The server notes the connection made via a console.log

Thusly I pass in nodejs.example.com, 9999, sockjs/websocket into the host, port and path fields respectively.

The node server however never sees the get connection issued.

(The thoughts behind this is the server has a heavy php backend installed and by having it tell node when to send data to the clients we can have more real time interactions and remove polling without having to do a full blown switchover).

TLDR: I want to be able to send messages to a NodeJS/SockJS server from PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create a solution for myself that might not work in all scenarios but at least worked here. By having the node server host an additional server on another port that ran pure websockets I was able to use that port/server with no modifications to the websocket client class I am using.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled over this question and I want to contribute. I had exactly the same problem. I solved it by using Redis and the Publish/Subscribe pattern used in Redis.

In addition to your PHP and node.js server you install Redis. Predis library (https://github.com/nrk/predis) for PHP and redis-node (https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis) for node.js.

Example code:

***PHP***

```
$redis = new Client();
$redis->publish('updates', Random::getUniqueString());
```

***Redis client on node.js server***

```
require('redis').createClient()

redis.subscribe('updates');

redis.on('message', function(channel, data) {
    for (var id in sockets) {
        if (sockets.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
            sockets[id].write(data);
        }
    }
});
```

`sockets` are the socket connections from your SockJS.